# How to freeze the screen or stop the tweens in phaser using vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, game-development, phaser-framework, phaserjs

The code is in vuejs. I was trying to develop a game using phaser. But when the game is at the end I want to freeze the screen or stop the tweens.

But if I stop the tween when the game is over, on restarting the tweens are not restarting.

My main motive is to freeze the screen or stop the tween, but on restart it should run normally.

Please guide me what needs to be modified.

Here is my full code given below:

```
<template>
  <!-- <div v-if="!initialize">
    <button @click="initializeGame" class="btn">Start to Play</button>
  </div> -->
  <div ref="phaserContainer"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Phaser from 'phaser';
let gameOver = false;
let retryButton;
let okButton;
let tween1;
let tween2;
let tween3;
let tween4;

let image1;
let text1;

let image2;
let text2;

let image3;
let text3;

let image4;
let text4;

export default {
  data() {
      return {
        initialize: false,
        textQuestion: "",
        questionCounter: 1,
        quiz: [
            {
              question: "WHAT IS THE CAPITAL OF FRANCE?",
              answers: ["LONDON", "PARIS", "BERLIN", "ROME"],
              correctAnswer: "PARIS"
            },
            {
              question: "WHICH PLANET IS KNOWN AS THE RED PLANET?",
              answers: ["MARS", "JUPITER", "SATURN", "VENUS"],
              correctAnswer: "MARS"
            },
            {
              question: "WHAT IS THE NATIONAL FLOWER OF INDIA?",
              answers: ["ROSE", "LOTUS", "LILY", "JASMINE"],
              correctAnswer: "LOTUS"
            },
            {
              question: "WHAT IS THE CHEMICAL SYMBOL FOR WATER?",
              answers: ["O", "H2O", "CO2", "NaCl"],
              correctAnswer: "H2O"
            }
          ],
        questionIndex: 0,
        fishImage1: true,
        fishImage2: true,
        fishImage3: true,
        fishImage4: true
      }
  },
  watch: {
      questionCounter() {
          if(this.questionCounter > this.quiz.length) {
            this.initialize = false;
          }
      }
  },
  mounted() {
    //Initialize Phaser game
    //this.initPhaserGame();
    this.initializeGame();
  },
  methods: {
    initializeGame() {
       this.initialize = true;
       this.initPhaserGame();
    },
    getIndexOfAnswer(correctAnswer) {
      const currentQuestion = this.quiz[this.questionIndex];
      return currentQuestion.answers.indexOf(correctAnswer);
    },
    getNextQuestion() {
      this.questionCounter++;
      if(this.questionCounter <= this.quiz.length) {
        //Next quextion
        this.questionIndex = this.questionIndex + 1;
        this.textQuestion.setText(this.quiz[this.questionIndex].question);
        text1.setText(this.quiz[this.questionIndex].answers[0]);
        text2.setText(this.quiz[this.questionIndex].answers[1]);
        text3.setText(this.quiz[this.questionIndex].answers[2]);
        text4.setText(this.quiz[this.questionIndex].answers[3]);

        this.fishImage1 = true;
        this.fishImage2 = true;
        this.fishImage3 = true;
        this.fishImage4 = true;
      }
    },
    handleGameOver(obj) {
        // Stop any ongoing game actions, animations, or timers
        // For example:
        //obj.scene.stop("MainScene");
        
        // Show game over text or UI
        obj.add.text(400, 300, 'Game Over', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#fff' }).setOrigin(0.5);
        // this.textQuestion = this.add.text(5, 0, self.quiz[self.questionIndex].question).setFont('28px Arial Black').setFill('#ffffff').setShadow(2, 2, "#333333", 2);

        tween1.pause();
        tween2.pause();
        tween3.pause();
        tween4.pause();

        //  Buttons to control the Tween timescale
        retryButton = obj.add.image(500, 430, 'retry');
        const width = 100; // Desired width
        const height = 30; // Desired height
        retryButton.setScale(width / retryButton.width, height / retryButton.height);

        okButton = obj.add.image(300, 430, 'ok');
        okButton.setScale(width / okButton.width, height / okButton.height);
        
        // Allow the player to restart the game
        //Retry button
        retryButton.on('pointerdown', () => {
          //obj.scene.start("MainScene");
          // tween1.restart();
          // tween2.restart();
          // tween3.restart();
          // tween4.restart();
          //this.initPhaserGame();
          //window.location.reload();
          obj.scene.restart();
        });
        retryButton.setInteractive({
          pixelPerfect: false,
          useHandCursor: true
        });
        //Ok button
        okButton.on('pointerdown', () => {
          tween1.resume();
          tween2.resume();
          tween3.resume();
          tween4.resume();
          this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
        });
        okButton.setInteractive({
          pixelPerfect: false,
          useHandCursor: true
        });
        // retryButton.on('pointerdown', () => {
        //     // Reload the current scene or restart the game
        //     obj.scene.restart();
            
        //     // Reset any game state or variables
        //     //gameOver = false;
        // });
    },
    initPhaserGame() {
      const self = this;
      const MainScene = {
          preload() {
            // Load background image
            this.load.image('bg', 'src/assets/space/nebula.jpg');
            this.load.image('up', 'src/assets/ui/up-bubble.png');
            this.load.image('down', 'src/assets/ui/down-bubble.png');
            this.load.image('retry', 'src/assets/space/retry.png');
            this.load.image('ok', 'src/assets/space/ok.png');
            //this.load.spritesheet('fish', 'src/assets/sprites/fish-136x80.png', { frameWidth: 136, frameHeight: 80 });
            this.load.image('fish1', 'src/assets/space/ufo1.png');
            this.load.image('fish2', 'src/assets/space/ufo2.png');
            this.load.image('fish3', 'src/assets/space/ufo3.png');
            this.load.image('fish4', 'src/assets/space/ufo2.png');
          },
          create() {
            //Create background image
            this.add.image(400, 300, 'bg');

            //Create question
            self.textQuestion = this.add.text(5, 0, self.quiz[self.questionIndex].question).setFont('28px Arial Black').setFill('#ffffff').setShadow(2, 2, "#333333", 2);

            //###################################################################
            //######################First Fish###################################
            //###################################################################
            image1 = this.add.image(100, -150, 'fish1', 0);
            // Initialize text1 of fish1
            text1 = this.add.text(300, -150, self.quiz[self.questionIndex].answers[0], { fontSize: '20px', fill: '#fff' }).setOrigin(0.6,-2);

            //Onhover on fish1
            image1.setInteractive({
              pixelPerfect: false,
              useHandCursor: true
            });

            //Onclick on fish1
            image1.on('pointerdown', function (){
              //alert("fish 1");
              if(self.initialize){
                if(self.fishImage1){
                  //Get index of correct answer
                  const correctAnswerIndex = self.getIndexOfAnswer(self.quiz[self.questionIndex].correctAnswer);
                  if(correctAnswerIndex == 0) {
                    alert("CORRECT ANSWER");

                    self.getNextQuestion();
                  } else {
                    self.fishImage1 = false;
                    //image1.off('pointerdown');
                    alert("WRONG ANSWER");
                  }
                }                
              }
            });
            //code to move fish1 when moving up and down
            tween1 = this.tweens.add({
                targets: image1,
                //cycle: true,
                props: {
                    x: { value: 600, },
                    y: { value: 600, },
                },
                duration: 5000,
                ease: 'Sine.easeInOut',
                //yoyo: true,
                repeat: -1,
                // onComplete: function (tween) {
                //     if (tween.targets[0].x >= 800) {
                //         tween.targets[0].x = -150; // Reset position to the left
                //     }
                // }
                // onComplete: () => { image1.setPosition(-70, 300); },
                // onUpdate: function () {
                //     // Check if image1.x is greater than a certain value
                //     if (image1.x > 800) {
                //         // Update flipX property to true
                //         image1.flipX = true;
                //     } else {
                //         // Reset flipX property to false
                //         image1.flipX = false;
                //     }
                // }
            });
            //text1 to follow fish1 when moving up and down

            this.tweens.add({
                targets: text1,
                //cycle: true,
                props: {
                    x: { value: 300 },
                    y: { value: 600 },
                },
                duration: 6000,
                ease: 'Power1',
                //yoyo: true,
                repeat: -1,
                //onComplete: () => { text1.setPosition(-70, 300); },                
            });

            //###################################################################
            //##################Second fish######################################
            //###################################################################
            image2 = this.add.image(300, -150, 'fish2', 1).setScale(0.95);
            // Initialize text2 of fish2
            text2 = this.add.text(300, 150, self.quiz[self.questionIndex].answers[1], { fontSize: '20px', fill: '#fff' }).setOrigin(0.6,-2);
            //Onhover on fish2
            image2.setInteractive({
              pixelPerfect: false,
              useHandCursor: true
            });
            //Onclick on fish2
            image2.on('pointerdown', function (){
              //alert("fish 2");
              if(self.initialize){
                if(self.fishImage2){
                  //Get index of correct answer
                  const correctAnswerIndex = self.getIndexOfAnswer(self.quiz[self.questionIndex].correctAnswer);
                  if(correctAnswerIndex == 1) {
                    alert("CORRECT ANSWER");
                    
                    self.getNextQuestion();
                  } else {
                    self.fishImage2 = false;
                    //image2.off('pointerdown');
                    alert("WRONG ANSWER");
                  }  
                }   
              }         
            });
            //code to move fish2 when moving up and down
            tween2 = this.tweens.add({
                targets: image2,
                props: {
                    x: { value: 900, },
                    y: { value: 800,  },
                },
                duration: 5000,
                ease: 'Sine.easeInOut',
                //yoyo: true,
                repeat: -1,
                // onComplete: () => { image2.setPosition(-150, 300); },
                // onUpdate: function () {
                //     // Check if image2.x is greater than a certain value
                //     if (image2.x > 850) {
                //         // Update flipX property to true
                //         image2.flipX = true;
                //     } else {
                //         // Reset flipX property to false
                //         image2.flipX = false;
                //     }
                // }
            });            
            //text2 to follow fish2 when moving up and down
            this.tweens.add({
                targets: text2,
                //cycle: true,
                props: {
                    x: { value: 300 },
                    y: { value: 900  },
                },
                duration: 6000,
                ease: 'Power1',
                //yoyo: true,
                repeat: -1,                
            });

            //###################################################################
            //##################Third fish#######################################
            //###################################################################
            image3 = this.add.image(250, 110, 'fish3', 2).setScale(1.25);
            // Initialize text3 of fish3
            text3 = this.add.text(250, 110, self.quiz[self.questionIndex].answers[2], { fontSize: '20px', fill: '#fff' }).setOrigin(0.6,-2);
            //Onhover on fish3
            image3.setInteractive({
              pixelPerfect: false,
              useHandCursor: true
            });
            //Onclick on fish3
            image3.on('pointerdown', function (){
              //alert("fish 3");
              if(self.initialize){
                if(self.fishImage3){
                  //Get index of correct answer
                  const correctAnswerIndex = self.getIndexOfAnswer(self.quiz[self.questionIndex].correctAnswer);
                  if(correctAnswerIndex == 2) {
                    alert("CORRECT ANSWER");

                    self.getNextQuestion();
                  } else {
                    self.fishImage3 = false;
                    //image3.off('pointerdown');
                    alert("WRONG ANSWER");
                  }
                }
              }
            });
            //code to move fish3 when moving up and down
            tween3 = this.tweens.add({
                targets: image3,
                props: {
                    x: { value: 500 },
                    y: { value: 600 },
                },
                duration: 5000,
                ease: 'Linear',
                //yoyo: true,
                repeat: -1
            });
            //text3 to follow fish3 when moving up and down
            this.tweens.add({
                targets: text3,
                //cycle: true,
                props: {
                    x: { value: 150 },
                    y: { value: 700 },
                },
                duration: 5000,
                ease: 'Power1',
                //yoyo: true,
                repeat: -1,                
            });

            //###################################################################
            //##################Fourth fish######################################
            //###################################################################
            
            //image4 = this.add.image(400, 0, 'fish4', 1).setScale(1.45);
            image4 = this.add.image(150, 0, 'fish4', 1).setScale(1.45);
            // Initialize text4 of fish4            
            text4 = this.add.text(400, 0, self.quiz[self.questionIndex].answers[3], { fontSize: '20px', fill: '#fff' }).setOrigin(0.6,-2.7);
            //Onhover on fish4
            image4.setInteractive({
              pixelPerfect: false,
              useHandCursor: true
            });
            //Onclick on fish4
            image4.on('pointerdown', function (){
              //alert("fish 4");
              if(self.initialize){
                if(self.fishImage4){
                  //Get index of correct answer
                  const correctAnswerIndex = self.getIndexOfAnswer(self.quiz[self.questionIndex].correctAnswer);
                  if(correctAnswerIndex == 3) {
                    alert("CORRECT ANSWER");

                    self.getNextQuestion();
                  } else {
                    self.fishImage4 = false;
                    //image4.off('pointerdown');
                    alert("WRONG ANSWER");
                  }
                }
              }
            });
            //code to move fish4 when moving up and down
            // this.tweens.add({
            //     targets: image4,
            //     props: {
            //         x: { value: 700, duration: 2000, flipX: true },
            //         y: { value: 50, duration: 15000,  },
            //     },
            //     ease: 'Sine.easeInOut',
            //     yoyo: true,
            //     repeat: -1
            // });
            tween4 = this.tweens.add({
                targets: image4,
                props: {
                    x: { value: 150 },
                    y: { value: 700 },
                },
                duration: 5000,
                ease: 'Power1',
                //yoyo: true,
                repeat: -1,
            });
            //text4 to follow fish4 when moving up and down
            this.tweens.add({
                targets: text4,
                props: {
                    x: { value: 150 },
                    y: { value: 900 },
                },
                duration: 5000,
                ease: 'Power1',
                //yoyo: true,
                repeat: -1,                
            });

            //  Buttons to control the Tween timescale

            // retryButton.on('pointerdown', () => {

            // });
            // retryButton.setInteractive({
            //   pixelPerfect: false,
            //   useHandCursor: true
            // });
            // okButton.on('pointerdown', () => {

            // });
            // okButton.setInteractive({
            //   pixelPerfect: false,
            //   useHandCursor: true
            // });

            // const downButton = this.add.image(70, 530, 'down').setInteractive();

            // downButton.on('pointerdown', () => {

            //     if (this.tweens.timeScale > 0)
            //     {
            //         this.tweens.timeScale -= 0.1;
            //     }

            //     text.setText('Global timeScale: ' + this.tweens.timeScale.toFixed(2));

            // });

            // const upButton = this.add.image(730, 530, 'up').setInteractive();

            // upButton.on('pointerdown', () => {

            //     if (this.tweens.timeScale < 9.9)
            //     {
            //         this.tweens.timeScale += 0.1;
            //     }

            //     text.setText('Global timeScale: ' + this.tweens.timeScale.toFixed(2));

            // });
          },
          update() {
            if(self.questionCounter > self.quiz.length) {
                // Set gameOver flag to true
                gameOver = true;
                
                // Call a function to handle game over
                this.scene.stop("MainScene");
                self.handleGameOver(this);
            }

            //###################Fish1
            // Move the object - copy movement of fish1 with text1
            image1.x += 1;
            image1.y += 1;
            // Update text position
            text1.x = image1.x;
            text1.y = image1.y;

            // if (image1.x > 800) {              
            //   image1.setPosition(-150, 300); // Reset position to the left of the screen
            //   // image1.flipX = true;

            //   // text1.setPosition(-70, 300);
            // }

            //###################Fish2
            // Move the object - copy movement of fish2 with text2
            image2.x += 1;
            image2.y += 1;
            // Update text position
            text2.x = image2.x;
            text2.y = image2.y;
              
            //###################Fish3
            // Move the object - copy movement of fish3 with text3
            image3.x += 1;
            image3.y += 1;
            // Update text position
            text3.x = image3.x;
            text3.y = image3.y;

            //###################Fish4
            // Move the object - copy movement of fish4 with text3
            image4.x += 1;
            image4.y += 1;
            // Update text position
            text4.x = image4.x;
            text4.y = image4.y;
            
          }
        };
      // Create a Phaser game configuration
      const config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        parent: this.$refs.phaserContainer,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        scene: MainScene 
      };

      // Create Phaser game instance
      new Phaser.Game(config);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Please check the function 
```
handleGameOver
```
there on  

```
tween1.pause();
        tween2.pause();
        tween3.pause();
        tween4.pause();
```

the game is not restarting normally. Please guide me.

Comment: I recommend updating your question, adding your last comment and following the guides https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. posting all your code, makes it hard for people to answer. At the very least format your code and remove all unneeded / commented-out code.

Comment: btw.: if phaser-game freezes, you can check the browser console for errors. _(looking/posting errors might help find a solution)_